# How can I delete row[6] from datarow row inside foreach loop in the code below?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DataTable dt` in which I am trying to add two more columns. I succeed on that. But when I try to delete row[6] after getting the data, I am facing problems to delete that. I am looking for a way to remove a particular row.

```
protected void gvTimeSheet_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int intUserID = TypeConvert.IsNullInt32(ddlUsers.SelectedValue, 0);
    DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(UCFromDate.selectedDate);
    DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(UCToDate.selectedDate);
    string strQuery = "EXEC SPRptUserTimeSheet_AP @User=" + intUserID + ",@dateFrom='" + fromDate + "',@dateTo='" + toDate + "'";
    dt = DataHelper.ExecuteQuery(strQuery);
    dt.Columns.Add("Booked Hrs");
    dt.Columns.Add("Time Zone");



    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string userName = row[0].ToString();
        string bookedHr = row[6].ToString();
        string timezone = row[7].ToString();

        if (userName == string.Empty)
        {
            row[0] = ddlUsers.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        if (bookedHr == string.Empty)
        {
            row["Booked Hrs"] = 0.0;
        }
        if (bookedHr != string.Empty)
        {
            row["Booked Hrs"] = objCommon.fnGetEffortInHrMinFormat(Convert.ToInt32(bookedHr));
        }

        if (timezone == "0")
        {
            row["Time Zone"] = "Offshore";

        }
        if (timezone == "1")
        {
            row["Time Zone"] = "Onsite";
        }

    }
    ViewState["dtExport"] = dt;
}
}
```

Comment: where is your delete code for extra two columns..

Comment: i want to delete inside foreach loop.

Comment: i dont want to delete my extra column. i just want to delete  row[6] and row[7] inside foreach loop. Kutty Rajesh Valangai

Comment: here you added two columns to DataTable what you want to delete in foreach loop,,,

Comment: Ya i have added two new column. but when i get the value of row[6] and row[7] inside foreach loop i want to delete that row[6] and row[7].

Comment: Try it with `dt.Rows.RemoveAt(6)`.

Comment: Please use parameters instead of string concatenation in your sql statement. You are now open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not really make sense:

To understand *why*, you need to consider what the expression `row[6]` really means. It means

> the value of column 6 in this row.

So the only way to realistically remove the column 6 from the row would be to delete it from the table:

```
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(6);
```

That would get rid of the column alright. But then you have removed it for **ALL** rows.

So you cannot do this from within the `foreach` loop. If you did you would remove

- the 6th column the first time,
- the (orignally) 7th column the second time, and
- the (originally) 8th column the third time through the loop,
- etc..

Until you have an exception that you are trying to remove a column outside the bounds of the Column collection.

So, if you must indeed get rid of column 6 do so after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an item from a collection, that collection has been changed and you can't continue to enumerate through `foreach` instead use `for` loop.

add snippet,

```
for(int i = dt.Rows.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
if(i==6||i==7)
{
 dr.Delete();
}

}
```

Comment: It don't think he means to delete dt.Row[6] from the table, but the 6th and 7th columns of the row.

Comment: Thank you for your help kutty-rajesh-valangai but it will gelete the 6 and 7 the row of datatable. But i want to delete 6th and 7th row of each datatable's rows.

Comment: @babluParhi - you want to delete `row[6]`, which is a field. To describe it as "row of a row" is very confusing.

Comment: ya..right Hans Kesting..i want to delete that field.. Then how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use **for** loop instead of **foreach** loop. Try this

```
for (int i =dt.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
   if (true) 
   {
      dt.Rows[i].Delete();
   }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
ViewState["dataTable"]=dt;
```

Comment: No praveen it will delete the from dt.

Comment: do you want to delete the 6th and 7th row positon of the datatable right?

Comment: No i wany to delete 6th and 7th row position of datarow @praveen

Comment: ya i try this...But it is deleting the 6th and 7th rows of datatable but i have to delete 6th and 7th field of datarow. @praveen

Comment: Do you want to remove particular cell (field) of a datarow or to remove a column?